# difference between containers

Tags: c++

I'm a little bit confused, can somebody please explain the main difference between those types of containers:

```
map
list
set
array
```

I'm asking about C++.

Comment: Which C++ text book are you using? If it doesn't cover this, you should get hold of Josutis's excellent book http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/index.html.

Comment: Or perhaps you should consult [the SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) and decide what information you find interesting.

Comment: Are you asking about what an array is or a vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

> - Maps are a kind of associative containers that stores elements formed by the combination of a key value and a mapped value.
> - Lists are a kind of sequence containers. As such, their elements are ordered following a linear sequence.
> - Sets are a kind of associative containers that stores unique elements, and in which the elements themselves are the keys.

Arrays are also a kind of sequence containers, just much lower level than `list`. Their size is fixed, they don't manage memory dynamically and aren't generic. They are inherited from C.

Answer (score 2):

[SGI has a good tutorial and documentation on STL for the map, list and set](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).  For arrays any basic C or C++ tutorial will cover this information.

- map is a container which maps a key to a value, think of it like a lookup table.
- list is a container which is a sequence that supports both forward and backwards traversal
- set is a container which stores a list of unique items
- array is a consecutive block of memory which any item is accessible in constant time but cannot grow after its initial size.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ : you can consider it!"